# Playwright: Test 1 testCase with different data from JSON file

Tags: json, typescript, foreach, playwright, test-data

Hi i'm having difficulty in reading data from Json file as I want to read different data from json file and pass it to 1 test case.
Json file :

```
              {
              "allCaes":
                    {
                   "TestCase1":
                            {
                          "originInput": "",
                         "destinationInput": ""
                            },
                   "TestCase2":
                            {
                           "originInput": "",
                           "destinationInput": "",
 
                            },
                     }
                  }
```

My code:
import { allCases } from '../abcData.json';

```
       Object.keys(allCases).forEach(data => {
       test('close selected origin', async ({ page }) => {
       const homepage = new abcHomePage(page);
       await homepage.goto();
       await homepage.closeSelectedOrigin();
       await homepage.enterOriginInput(allCases.TestCase1.originInput);
       await homepage.enterDestinationInput();
       await homepage.selectStartDate();
       await homepage.selectEndDate();
```

}
I want to make it generic for all test data present in json file
await homepage.enterOriginInput(allCases.**TestCase1**.originInput); dont want to specify testCase1

Answer (score 1):

First you need an array in the json-file:

```
{
    "persons":[
        {
            "name":"Alex",
            "lastname":"Test"
        },
        {
            "name":"John",
            "lastname":"Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then use this code to import and read the data:

```
const { persons } = require('../data.json'); // or use: import { persons } from '../data.json';

persons.forEach((item, index) => {
  test(`Some text - Iteration: ${index+1}`, async ({ page }) => {
    await page.locator('#element').fill(persons[index].name);
    await page.locator('#element2').fill(persons[index].lastname);
  });
})
```